# How to measure effectiveness of warehouse pickers?

Tags: mean, types-of-averages

Workers in a warehouse pick items in a pick-list to fulfil orders.

The number of orders a worker fulfils in a shift depends on how quickly they work.

But the total number of orders received per day changes - for instance, fewer orders are received at weekends. (More orders means more work available.)

Also, the headcount of a shift varies due to assigned staffing levels and absences. (Lower headcount means more work available.)

Lastly, the orders can vary in complexity, so some take longer.

Is a simple average of number of orders per worker a fair measure of effectiveness or is it biased against weekend staff? Is measuring average picking time fair given the varying complexity?

If not, what measures are better?